# Problems while setting up the development environment for Eclipse SmartHome

Tags: eclipse, openhab

I am having problems with setting up the Eclipse IDE for editing source code of SmartHome on Windows 10. I have done everything as it is described in the ***[Setting Up a Development Environment](https://www.eclipse.org/smarthome/documentation/development/ide.html)*** guide.

However everything works until I open up the workbench. At the first start the so called "setup tasks" will be performed automatically which takes about 5 min. After that I still got like 100 errors of 200 items and a bunch of warnings.

In the official guide they say this might be normal. After performing the "manual setup tasks" however (which can be found under "help" in the menu bar) most errors should be gone, which does not happen in my case. Even after rebuilding all of the loaded projects there are **still errors and warnings remaining**.

Has anybody had similar issues and maybe a solution for that problem?

Comment: Your question is not related to programming directly, so please use another site for this. For example it’s can be https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions (involving specific problems and code), rather than debugging software installation. Your best bet would be Eclipse support forums or mailing lists.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Could you please explain why you think source code related errors displayed in a development environment are not related to programming?

Comment: @StepanNovikov Could you please explain why you think source code related errors displayed in a development environment are not related to programming?

Comment: Please add some of the remaining errors to your question.